# rails parameters in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a form for updating or saving a saved message.

```
<% form_for @draft, :url => {:controller => "drafts", :action => "draft_actions"} do |f|%>

      subject
  <%=f.text_field :subject %>

      recipients
  <%=f.text_field :draft_recipients %>

 <br /> <%= f.text_area :body %>


      <%= submit_tag "save", :name => "resave_draft"%>
      <%= submit_tag "send", :name => "send_draft" %>

<% end %>
```

but I want the recipients to be displayed in a nice way, separated by commas : `user1, user2, user3` instead of `user1user2user3`
My problem is : I don't understand how to have the `:recipients` symbol map to  my recipient attribute in my draft model, but still have the view displaying the recipients displayed how I want

The code for my `draft` model is

```
class Draft < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :message
belongs_to :draft_recipient, :class_name => "User"
delegate :created_at, :subject, :user, :body, :draft_recipients,  :to => :message
```

The code for my Message model is the following

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_many :recipients, :through => :message_copies
has_many :draft_recipients, :through => :drafts
has_many :message_copies
has_many :drafts, :class_name => "Draft", :foreign_key => :message_id

attr_accessor :to #array  of people to send to
attr_accessible :subject, :body, :to, :recipients, :author, :user
```

I'm sure there's a fairly straightforward way to do that, but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: Could you put the code for the Draft model?

Comment: Where's `recipients`? If `draft_recipients` replaces it, how is it defined in the `Message`model?

Comment: sorry, it is draft_recipients indeed.

Comment: could you post the `Message` model then, if that's where `draft_recipients` is defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%=f.text_field :draft_recipients, :value => @draft.draft_recipients.join(',') %>
```

Might work out for you. However, are you handling the conversion back in the controller? This won't bind exactly right when you submit.

Comment: Ok, I had planned to convert back into the controller. I'll try this. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Where/how could I habe found out about the :value attribute myself? I somehow seem to suck at reading api docs...

Comment: That's a good question @Arthur. The docs don't spell out that `:value` is there - but think of what gets converted to HTML in the end. You can apply any thing there. A common one, that it knows how to deal with, are `data-custom` attributes. `:data => { :custom => "value", :morecustom => "morevalue" }` gets turned into `data-custom="value" data-morecustom="morevalue"` per http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml. You can make up other attributes as well, that just makes sense in your application (for jQuery selectors maybe?).