# Updating several records for same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok I'm really feeling I'm missing the rails way on this one.
Following my last question [rails parameters in form_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555901/rails-parameters-in-form-for/7556178#7556178), I can correctly update the message contents but am struggling with updating the recipients

My Draft model

```
class Draft < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :message
belongs_to :draft_recipient, :class_name => "User"
delegate :created_at, :subject, :user, :body, :draft_recipients,  :to => :message
...
```

My Message Model

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_many :recipients, :through => :message_copies
has_many :draft_recipients, :through => :drafts
has_many :message_copies
has_many :drafts, :class_name => "Draft", :foreign_key => :message_id

attr_accessor :to #array  of people to send to
attr_accessible :subject, :body, :to, :recipients, :author, :user
...
```

In my controller I want to do something like

```
new_draft_recipients = params[:draft][:draft_recipients].split(",")
@draft.update_attributes(:draft_recipients => new_draft_recipients)
```

which obviously doesn't work. When I try update each record comparing old (from the database )and new recipients (passed through the form), the algorithm gets ridiculously complicated. I feel what is missing is proper associations, but I don't manage to understand which. I know this is really simple. Thanks for your help

Comment: This is very confusing. Is your `@draft` variable an instance of `Draft` or `Message`? You should not expect to be able to update the `draft_recipients` through an instance of `Draft` by delegating to its corresponding message, because you'll have one draft for each recipient, the way you have modelled it. What do you think your `Draft` class represents, and what are your other models?

Comment: @draft is an instance of Draft, but I thought several records in a table could map to a single instance, which I know understand it cannot. So I guess the idea is to update all the drafts instances through the corresponding message instance! Seems obvious.